# Spyder, clean Win installation, ver. 4.2.3 - pip gives message "No module named pip"

Tags: python-3.x, pip, spyder

I have Spyder, clean Win10 installation, ver. 4.2.3.

When I run command **pip**, it gives message:

```
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\Python\python.exe: No module named pip
```

I restarted Spyder, Win10, nothing helps.

How to fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have python 3.4+ then pip should be installed with python.
To check that, you can run

```
pip help
```

in your windows command line.

However, if it isn't the case then download the [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) file and run

```
python get-pip.py
```

and the pip installation should start. You can use `pip help` to verify this.
Another source of the problem might be that pip isn't listed in your PATH variables and thus isn't recognized by your command line.

Comment: I supposed that python is integral part of the Spyder installation. If not, should I install python on its own? Anyway, I downloaded 'get-pip.py' and run it as you proposed, and now it works as supposed. Solved. Thanks!

Comment: If you downloaded Spyder via Anaconda (which I recommend) then you shouldn't download python on the side. Anaconda takes care of everything if you follow the installation steps. If you have any doubts, I'd advice you uninstall and re-install the Anaconda suite.

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) We don't provide `pip` in our Windows app to prevent people breaking Spyder by installing any kind of packages with it.

The best way to use other packages that don't come with our app is to install [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html), create a [conda environment](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands) after that with the packages you want to use and `spyder-kernels`, and finally [connect Spyder](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-existing-environment) to that env.