# Python 3.11.0: "No module named pip" on Spyder (5.4.0), but Terminal shows "ensurepip" as "Requirement already satisfied"

Tags: python, pandas, pip

[image]

Hi. I installed Python 3.11.0 and Spyder IDE 5.4.0 a few days ago. It had been running smoothly. I tried entering "pip install pandas" (to install pandas through the console) but it says "no module named pip" (as shown in the picture).

I already ran "py -m ensurepip" through PowerShell but it says "Requirement already satisfied". "pip" is (supposedly) already in my site packages.

The IDE indicates that it's running Python 3.8.10 64-bit, which I thought was the issue (because of Python 3.11.0 being a newer version), but otherwise, Spyder has been working perfectly.
What should I do?

Comment: Please see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67049678/13663981

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the python installation used in your IDE vs the one used in Powershell.

From your screenshot, it looks like the IDE comes with its own python and using that installation. Your powershell is probably using a different python installation.

You can update your IDE to use your system default so that the packages you installed globally are also available in your IDE.